# How do I get my ASP.NET Web Application to work with AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, appharbor

I've been working on a web application, using ASP.NET Web Application with C# in Visual Studio 2010, and have just started and am trying to deploy it to AppHarbor. I can push my project to AppHarbor just fine and with no errors, but when I try to access my web application with the URL, I get an error:

*HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.*

When I run my application through Visual Studio 2010 it works just fine, and I have managed to get applications to work with appHarbor before, using ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. I would guess that there are something wrong in my code, like in the webconfig file for example, but I cannot figure out what. I've been searching around for a great while, trying to get a clue of what I'm doing wrong, but it seems hopeless for my specific problem.

Is there something specific you have to do to make a web application run with appHarbor, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: have you disabled the custom errors? so you can really see the YSOD with the correct error and stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through the [AppHarbor deploy FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions). In particular, I would download the build output and verify that AppHarbor deploys what you expect.